# IMG and Favicon not displaying

Tags: html, css, image

I've been trying to display an image but it doesn't work. I tried to take off the **/** at the end of the `<img>` tag, but it doesn't work neither. My favicon doesn't appear too, and I don't know why.
Here is my code:

```css
img.check {
  width: 15%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 790px;
}
.text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 625px;
}
.redirect {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 830px;
  color: blue;
}
.redirect:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Your Password has been changed.</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/zimbrafav.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <img src="img/check.png" class="check" alt="check">
  <div class="text">
    <p>
      <h1>Your password has been changed!</h1>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="redirect">
    <p>
      <h1><a href="http://google.be/">Go to Google > </a></h1>
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In which folder are the images located (relative to the file you're using them)?

Comment: Did your html file is hosted or you test it locally?

Comment: The html files are hosted. They are in a folder called img

Comment: Did you try to convert your png image to ico? you can find online tools for that. For example : http://convertico.com/ Also, did you try to add full URL to your image : http://yourdomain/yourimage_path ?

Comment: Well, img/check.png means img folder is placed in the root of the project. 
Is that the case? Try adding 2 dots, like ../img/check.png .

You messed something with the path. How about reverse slash, does that do anything? So, not / but \

Comment: What's the full URL to one of the images?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure but maybe it's because you are working with relative paths instead of absolute.

So

```
<img src="img/check.png" class="check" alt="check"/>
```

would turn into

```
<img src="/img/check.png" class="check" alt="check"/>
```